# Showing two sets have the same cardinality

Tags: functions, set-theory, cardinals

So I understand two sets have the same cardinality if you can map a function between them that is one-to-one and onto, but does it have to be the same function? Would it worked if I mapped one function that is onto, and another one that is one-to-one? If not, why?

Comment: Relevant theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem

Comment: Weird question.  But, no, if you can find a function that is 1-1 and another that is onto then they have the same cardinality.

Comment: Thing is $f:X-> Y $ being 1-1 means X "fits into" Y.  And $g:X->Y $ being onto means Y "fits into" X.  So equal cardilaty.

Comment: @fleablood Not clear from the OP's formulation that the two functions are going in the same direction. From a one-to-one function $f:X\to Y$ and an onto function $g:Y\to X,$ you can't conclude that $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality. Even if you have a one-to-one function $f:X\to Y$ and an onto function $g:X\to Y,$ you need the AXIOM OF CHOICE to conclude that $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: Yeah, you may be right.

Comment: @fleablood Without the axiom of choice, you can define an injection $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\cup\omega_1$ and a surjection $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\cup\omega_1,$ but you can't prove that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\cup\omega_1$ have the same cardinality, i.e., you can't prove that there is an injection $h:\omega_1\to\mathbb R.$

Comment: No.  You *are* right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of when sets $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality is that there exists a function $f:X\to Y$ which is *both* one-to-one and onto.  So according to the definition, you need a single function with both properties at once.

However, it turns out that if you have separate functions $X\to Y$ with just one of the properties each, this implies there exists a function with both at once.  Specifically, suppose $g:X\to Y$ is one-to-one and $h:X\to Y$ is onto.  Take a function $i:Y\to X$ which is a sort of "inverse" to $h$, in the sense that for each $y\in Y$, $i(y)$ is one of the points $x\in X$ such that $h(x)=y$ (we know that at least one such $x$ exists since $h$ is onto).  That is, we have $h(i(y))=y$ for all $y\in Y$.

I claim now that $i:Y\to X$ is one-to-one.  Indeed, suppose that $i(y)=i(y')$.  Applying $h$ to both sides, we get $h(i(y))=h(i(y'))$.  But $h(i(y))=y$ and $h(i(y'))=y'$, so this means $y=y'$.  Thus $i$ is one-to-one.

We now have both a one-to-one function $g:X\to Y$ and a one-to-one function $i:Y\to X$.  The [Schröder-Bernstein Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) now says there exists a function $f:X\to Y$ which is both one-to-one and onto.  (We can define $f$ in terms of $g$ and $i$, but it is pretty complicated--see the link above for more details).

Thus if you have one function $X\to Y$ which is one-to-one and another function $X\to Y$ which is onto, this implies $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality.

[As a caveat, the existence of a function $i$ as described in the second paragraph above requires the axiom of choice: for each $y\in Y$, you must *choose* one $x\in X$ such that $h(x)=y$.  In fact, without the axiom of choice, the final result may not be true.  As bof commented, there exists a one-to-one map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\omega_1$ and also an onto map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\omega_1$, but it is impossible to prove $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\cup\omega_1$ have the same cardinality without using the axiom of choice.]

Comment: The axiom of choice is a BIG caveat...